# Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, java-ee, google-app-engine

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web (JSP) con eclipse con el plugin de google app engine y me lanza un error al pulsar el botón enviar:

> "Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL"

he probado con "get" y si funciona, pero en este caso me interesa hacerlo con post. ¿Alguna solución?

Código de la JSP:
    
    
       
           
           Hello App Engine

```
   <body>   
       <form action="/hello" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="name"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Código del servlet

```
public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) 
  throws IOException {

response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

String name = request.getParameter("name");
response.getWriter().print("hola " + name + "\r\n");
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si cambias el nombre del método de `doGet` a `doPost`?

Comment: Que se soluciona. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta sobreescribiendo el metodo [`doPost`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) para poder recibir request de tipo post:

```
public class HelloAppEngine extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    response.getWriter().print("hola " + name + "\r\n");

}

    //....
```

Comment: Listo. Esa fue la solución. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra haber ayudado.

Comment: @kabi404 para agradecer la ayuda marca la respuesta como correcta, así alentaras a que Einer y otros usuarios te ayuden, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

reciban un cordial saludo.

Después de documentarme y hacer muchas pruebas, para que no tengan mas problemas con los métodos GET y POST de sus Servlets, es mejor que incluya los dos métodos en cada uno de sus Servlets de la siguiente forma.

```
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

// Manipular la petición enviada por el cliente
// utilizando el atributo method=get.
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

// Manipular la petición enviada por el cliente
// utilizando el atributo method=post.
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

// Devuelve una descripción breve.
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Servlet muestraProductos";
}
```

}

A mi me funciono perfectamente y yo se que les servirá a Ustedes también. Espero sus Comentarios...!! ☺